# Spring-GraphQL: source of source in @SchemaMapping

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I'm looking for a way to access source object of the source object used in graphql @SchemaMapping.

```java
record Children() {}
record Parent(List<Children> childrens, String surname) {}
```

```java
@SchemaMapping
String surname(Children children) {
  return "" // should access parent.surname()
}
```

```
type Parent {
  children: [Children]
  surname: String
}

type Children {
  surname: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should update your **Children** record with the fields you declare in your schema (initially, the *surname* String):

Then, I would suggest you included a way to link a **Children** to a **Parent** different to the *surname* (because as I believe from what you ask, that is not an option): for example, a *parentId*.

```
record Children(Long, parentId, String surname) {}
record Parent(Long id, List<Children> childrens, String surname) {}

type Parent {
  id: ID
  children: [Children]
  surname: String
}

type Children {
  parentId: ID
  surname: String
}
```

Then you could implement your schema mapping with a filter or whichever business method you have:

```
@SchemaMapping
String surname(Children children)
  return db.stream()
  .filter(aParent -> aParent.id()==children.parentId())
  .findAny()
  .orElseGet(()->...) //etc
  .surname();
}
```